# How to conditionally include a Hibernate annotation?

Tags: mysql, scala, hibernate, playframework, hana

I have the code below in Play for Scala to access a SAP Hana table with Hibernate. I need to implement the same code with MySql, but the problem is that MySql doesn't support sequences (it works with AUTO_INCREMENT columns) and the code breaks because I have to specify `@SequenceGenerator` for Hana. Is there a way to compile this code with a condition to exclude the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation, so it works for MySql and Hana at the same time?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
class ClientJpa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="generator", sequenceName = "cliSeq", allocationSize = 1)    
    var surrogateKey: Int = _
    var code: String = _
    var name: String = _
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer attempts to implement [Eugene's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995473/how-to-conditionally-include-a-hibernate-annotation#answer-50614632) (so if it works please give credit to Eugene).

Given the following definition of `@ifNotMysql` macro

```
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.annotation.{StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly}

object ifNotMysqlMacro {
  val targetIsMySql = sys.props.get("target-mysql").contains("true")

  def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._

    def mysqlAnnots(annotations: Seq[c.universe.Tree]): Seq[c.universe.Tree] =
      annotations
        .filterNot(_.toString.contains("SequenceGenerator"))
        .filterNot(_.toString.contains("GeneratedValue"))
        .:+(q"""new GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)""")

    val result = annottees.map(_.tree).toList match {
      case q"@..$annots var $pat: $tpt = $expr" :: Nil =>
        q"""
            @..${if (targetIsMySql) mysqlAnnots(annots) else annots}
            var $pat: $tpt = $expr
          """
    }
    c.Expr[Any](result)
  }
}

@compileTimeOnly("enable macro paradise to expand macro annotations")
class ifNotMysql extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro ifNotMysqlMacro.impl
}
```

if we write `@ifNotMysql @GeneratedValue(...) @SequenceGenerator` like so

```
@ifNotMysql 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name="generator", sequenceName = "cliSeq", allocationSize = 1)    
var surrogateKey: Int = _
```

and provide system property `target-mysql` like so

```
sbt -Dtarget-mysql=true compile
```

then `@SequenceGenerator` annotation will be excluded and `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` added like so

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
var surrogateKey: Int = _
```

This implementation is based on [scalamacros/sbt-example-paradise](https://github.com/scalamacros/sbt-example-paradise/blob/master/macros/src/main/scala/Macros.scala)

Comment: `@GeneratedValue` also needs to change depending on whether the compilation is on Hana or MySql, it seems that your solution handles only `@SequenceGenerator`

Comment: If environment is MySql then the following line should be inserted instead of the one in the example: `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

Comment: Mario, inserting a row in MySQL throws an error, are you sure it's replacing with `GenerationType.IDENTITY` when MySQL is set?

Comment: @ps0604 What is the error? Perhaps it is because I did not provide `generator` argument to `@GeneratedValue`, that is, `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "generator")`. I have edited the answer, please try again.

Comment: I still get the same error (by the way, I don't declare `generator` argument when using MySQL). The error seems to be related to a sequence that cannot read to generate the ID: `Exception: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet) (of class scala.util.Failure)]]`

Comment: By the way, if I compile in MySQL removing Hana annotations, this works fine with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` and without the `generator` argument.

Comment: I checked yours as the correct answer as the bounty period ended.

Comment: [Printing](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/api/Printers.html) the AST via `show(result)` I can confirm `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` is present.

Comment: @ps0604 Have you double checked `-Dtarget-mysql=true` is being picked up? Try printing the property value from some other class.

Comment: for my test I simply set `val targetIsMySql = true` to make sure

Comment: I'm using scala 2.11, not 2.12, could that be the problem?

Comment: Add `@compileTimeOnly("enable macro paradise to expand macro annotations")` above `class ifNotMysql ...` as shown in the edited answer, and recompile. Do you get a compiler error?

Comment: I get `not found: type compileTimeOnly` isn't this a 2.12 class? By the way, I'm using Play 2.5 and cannot upgrade to Scala 2.12

Comment: You might be missing an `import scala.annotation.compileTimeOnly`

Comment: The `ifNotMysql` macro should work in both 2.11 and 2.12.

Comment: I added the import and the @compileTimeOnly annotation, and get a compilation error in `var surrogateKey: Int = _`

Comment: Ok good, you are probably missing `addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)` in your `build.sbt`. According to [docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html): *"Macro annotations look like normal annotations to the vanilla Scala compiler, so if you forget to enable the macro paradise plugin in your build, your annotations will silently fail to expand."*

Comment: Added the `addCompilerPlugin` and now I get `macro annotation could not be expanded (the most common reason for that is that you need to enable the macro paradise plugin; another possibility is that you try to use macro annotation in the same compilation run that defines it)`

Comment: Maybe Play is causing the problem?

Comment: Macro needs to be defined in its own module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021707/what-does-it-mean-when-macro-annotation-cannot-be-used-in-the-same-compilation-t

Comment: If by module you mean a separate source code file containing the macro, then that's how I did it, it's even in a different package

Answer (score 2):

Probably not what you want to hear but AFAIK there's no way to conditionally include annotations. An alternative would be to include the common functionality in a `@MappedSuperclass` and inject the concrete instance as appropriate at build time depending on the environment. Something like this:-

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class AbstractClientJpa {
    var surrogateKey: Int   // abstract
    var code: String = _
    var name: String = _
}
```

...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
class HanaClientJpa extends AbstractClientJpa {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="generator", sequenceName = "cliSeq", allocationSize = 1)    
    var surrogateKey: Int = _
}
```

...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
class MySQLClientJpa extends AbstractClientJpa {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var surrogateKey: Int = _
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand your problem correctly I have 2 potential solutions for you. Both are general ideas and you'll have to do some legwork to actually implement them.

1. Use macros. Here is a [bit old article](https://www.47deg.com/blog/scala-macros-annotate-your-case-classes/) that does some AST manipulation to enrich case classes. You should be able to do something in that vein for your case. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42969692/compile-time-parameter-for-macro-expansion/43420124) is a way pass parameters to your macro at compile time. Main con with this route is that macro api was scala version dependent, somewhat messy, unstable and hard to find good documentation for last time I checked.
2. Use AspectJ. You should be able to [declare](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/annotations-declare.html) annotations you need on classes in build-time. Main con here is that you'll have to add AspectJ weaving to your build which may or may not be easy.

Comment: I have attempted to implement your suggestion and provided it as an answer. I hope that is ok. If not feel free to paste the code in your answer and I could remove mine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995473/how-to-conditionally-include-a-hibernate-annotation#answer-50666569

Comment: @MarioGalic I am ok with this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to do it is to provide a custom [`IdGeneratorStrategyInterpreter`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/IdGeneratorStrategyInterpreter.html) and register it using [`MetadataBuilder.applyIdGenerationTypeInterpreter`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/MetadataBuilder.html#applyIdGenerationTypeInterpreter-org.hibernate.boot.model.IdGeneratorStrategyInterpreter-). In your custom `IdGeneratorStrategyInterpreter` you can override `determineGeneratorName` to return `"identity"` constant for `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` if you know that the code is run against MySql and return `null` in all other cases to let the `FallbackInterpreter` do its default job (the string `"identity"` also comes from [`FallbackInterpreter.determineGeneratorName`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/d5d3b080f94ca2f498bada7747bbda1e0e3160a2/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/boot/internal/IdGeneratorInterpreterImpl.java#L211-L238) implementation). And you can do nothing in other methods and let the `FallbackInterpreter` do it's usual job.

P.S. Please also note that Hibernate's default [`SequenceStyleGenerator`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/enhanced/SequenceStyleGenerator.html) is actually aware of DBs not supporting "sequences" (exposed via [`Dialect.supportsSequences`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html#supportsSequences--)) and is able to emulate similar behavior using additional table. This might or might not be OK for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If ID in mysql is given auto-increment then in hibernate mapping ID should be IDENTITY

Replace that with

```
@Entity
@Table(name="clients")
class ClientJpa{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "generator")
  var surrogateKey: Int = _
  var code: String = _
  var name: String = _

 }
```

Hope it works....